# wkhtmltopdf repeating thead headers overlapping content

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

We're embedding wkhtmltopdf (0.12.1) in a Java application, using stdin and stdout for input/output. We want multiple (different) headers in our PDF, so instead of using the `--header-html` option we're using a `thead`, which is repeated on several pages. Here's a little example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
    <table style="page-break-after: always;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>My first header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>First content</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>My second header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Second content</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So far so good. Problems arise when the content spans multiple pages. The header is then displayed on top of the content, overlapping it. Example [html](https://gist.github.com/idserda/1cd9ba04732b2a2e6b90) and [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkoqjnnssniq7m3/example.pdf). Notice that the second header is rendered just fine, since the `tr` only spans one page.

Other people have had similar problems. There are some workarounds for this when you're using the `--header-html` option, such as adding `--header-spacing` or `--margin-top`, but these options have no effect on the repeated `thead`. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a known problem with wkhtmltopdf, see [issue 1524](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1524).

Answer (score 63):

I solved it with these three css rules:

```
thead { display: table-header-group; }
tfoot { display: table-row-group; }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

Comment: We had a complex multi-line header with muliple colspans and rowspans, and this solution worked perfectly for us.

Comment: thanks a lot!! I had a problem with this bug for a long time, and this solution worked perfectly in my PDF's

Comment: In my test, using the thead OR the tr rule worked. Seems like it just needs a nudge :-)

Comment: This is an older question, but this solution worked for me.

Comment: Did the job for me

Answer (score 16):

you solve this issue by adding the following css.

```
   tr {
         page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
```

Answer (score 9):

I found `tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }` worked to a point, but not when my headers spanned multiple lines. Since I wanted to keep my `thead` section, my solution was to switch the repeat off.

```
thead, tfoot {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

Comment: This did the job for me!

Comment: This causes that the theader is not printed on the following pages (wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5-1.msvc2015-win32)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt), I had the same issue resolved by removing the parent container (e.g. `<div>...</div>`).